# How can resolve the NPM issue? Stuck with npm start error

Tags: npm, create-react-app

The issue I have is that `npm start` cannot start. I tried to fix with audit, deleted node_dependency directory and re-installed with npm, nothing works.

One concrete issue I see is:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
  "webpack": "4.44.2"
```

Yet, I also see `npm -v webpack` -> `6.14.14`.  How do I need to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `npm -v webpack` command is not correct. it will return npm version and not the webpack version.

Try `npm ls webpack` . you can also check your `package.json` file for the packages you have. or run `npm ls` for the full list.

make sure to install the required dependency as it states.

Comment: The result is alo cryptic for me : >npm ls webpack -> reactfe1@0.1.0 S:\User\Webs\reactfe1
+-- react-scripts@4.0.3
| `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.44.2
`-- webpack@5.51.1

Comment: Does this mean that 5.51.1 is installed but UNMET DEPENDENCY of 4.44.2 ? Doesnt make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I could not solve the package problem with an informed debugging.

What I did was to (**npm install --global yarn**) and start the application through it (**yarn start**). It worked a lot to download the packages and eventually started the application.

So, I guess I need to switch to yarn after this point, which is ok, as long as it works :)